# How to add an element to an object storred locally using Hive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have this class:

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Client extends Equatable {
  @HiveField(0)
  late String _id;
  String get id => _id;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String fullName;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String email;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String phoneNumber;
  @HiveField(4)
  final String address;
  @HiveField(5)
  final String pictureUrl;
  @HiveField(6)
  final List<Product> likedProducts;
}
```

Knowing that it's being correctly storred locally in the phone, I want to add (remove) products to the list `likedProducts` whenever the user likes (unlikes) a product. How can I achieve this ?